# Закрывать приложение после каждого теста, что бы тест не падал

Tags: java, swing, junit

Я использую AssertJ для тестирования моего swing приложения. Мне нужно закрывать приложение после каждого теста, так как следующий тест будет его снова запускать. Проблема в том, что при использовании кода `frame.close();` или `System.exit(0);` тест падает с `exit code 0`. Я пробовал использовать что-то такого типа:

```
ApplicationLauncher.application(App.class).start();
pause(8000);
frame = WindowFinder.findFrame(FrameMatcher.withTitle("Application")).using(robot());
try {
    frame.close();
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
ApplicationLauncher.application(App.class).start();
pause(8000);
frame = WindowFinder.findFrame(FrameMatcher.withTitle("Application")).using(robot());
```

Но, после `frame.close();` получаю ту же проблему.Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой и может помочь советом?